# Sharepoint Designer 2013 doesnt have permission to access master file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error

I cant even make a new master file or replace it.  Says i need to give permissions on the web.  Any idea in this iteration of sharepoint?

EDIT I tried to save a new file over my master,  still doesnt work